# Apache mod_perl

Tags: apache-2.2, mac

I've tried to use mod_perl in apache that comes with Mac OS X 10.6.
To do that I add the following line in /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule perl_module        libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
```

But when I try to execute a perl script I have an error:

```
You don't have permission to access /~user1/mod_perl_rules1.pl on this server.
```

Inside of /var/log/apache2/error_log I found a mod_perl error:

```
[Mon Oct 03 01:04:09 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Options ExecCGI is off in this directory: /Users/user1/Sites/mod_perl_rules1.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put this in your conf:

```
<Directory "/Users/user1/Sites">
Options FollowSymLinks
Options +ExecCGI
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

As it said, you need to turn on the `ExecCGI` option in this directory, something like this:

```
<Directory "/Users/user1/Sites">
   Options +ExecCGI
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```